# Xcode 8 convert string of "yyyymmdd" to "ddmmyyyy"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm doing a card reader app and the date that comes in is in string format of `yyyyMMdd` and I need it to be converted to `ddMMyyyy` instead. May I know how I can proceed to do this?

Comment: Show your tries

Comment: Hi, please could you edit your answer to include the code you've written so far?

Comment: hi. it was a simple mistake i left out some words. here is the code that works. 

 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
                let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: birthdate)
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy"
                let date = dateFormatter.string(from: convertedDate!)

Comment: It works now. thanks

Comment: @EsvaranK did you check my answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
    NSString *strInputDateString = @"20170724"; // Your input date string.
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"]; // Set your main formate

    //Convert string into Date
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:strInputDateString];

    //Set new dateFormate
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];

     // You will get output in below string
    NSString *strOutputDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1];
    NSLog(@"%@",strOutputDateString);
```